# YOLOv4-deepsort does not detect while running on Google Colab's GPU

Tags: google-colaboratory, yolov4

I'm trying to do some object tracking on a video using Google Colab but I'm facing the issue below. Tracking is only done in the first frame of the video and not in the rest. I'm working with exactly same files and same commands both on my computer and Google Colab.

expected

[image: 1]

Google Colab

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like TensorFlow's version caused this problem. Here is my solution:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.3.0
```